# restarting tomcat after redeploying a web application

Tags: windows, sql-server-2005, tomcat, waffle, sqljdbc

Hi I'm using tomcat and using Waffle for windows authentication.  I'm also connecting to an SQL server using the windows credentials too using microsoft's driver.  I have a problem that everytime I reload or redeploy the application, i have to restart tomcat.  After some googling i've discovered that the dll was already loaded and thus cannot be reloaded.

I really need to redeploy application as i would need to update some functionality and it is very frustrating to ask the administrator to restart tomcat everytime i update the application.

When i was doing the same with glassfish i managed to work around this issue somehow, but cannot manage with tomcat